# Group object that contains store hours by day of week

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to group days by store hours.

This is what my object `this.customer.customerStoreStandardHours` looks like.

```
[
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Monday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Tuesday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Wednesday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"6:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Thursday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Friday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"Saturday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"4:00 PM"
   }
]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
storeGroupedHours() {
    if (this.customer.customerStoreStandardHours) {
        const groupedObject = this.customer.customerStoreStandardHours.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, i, array) {
            const key = currentValue.open + currentValue.close

            accumulator.ranges[key] = accumulator.ranges[key] || {};
            accumulator.days[key] = accumulator.days[key] || [];
            accumulator.ranges[key] = {
                open: currentValue.open,
                close: currentValue.close
            };

            accumulator.days[key].push({
                index: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'].indexOf(currentValue.dayOfWeek),
                name: currentValue.dayOfWeek
            })

            if (i == array.length - 1) {
                for (let key in accumulator.ranges) {
                    if (accumulator.ranges.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        accumulator.days[key].sort(function(a, b) {
                            return a.index - b.index
                        });
                        if (accumulator.days[key][0].name === accumulator.days[key][accumulator.days[key].length - 1].name) {
                            accumulator.grouped.push({
                                days: [
                                    accumulator.days[key][0].name,
                                ].join(''),
                                open: accumulator.ranges[key].open,
                                close: accumulator.ranges[key].close
                            });
                        } else {
                            accumulator.grouped.push({
                                days: [
                                    accumulator.days[key][0].name,
                                    accumulator.days[key][accumulator.days[key].length - 1].name
                                ].join('-'),
                                open: accumulator.ranges[key].open,
                                close: accumulator.ranges[key].close
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return accumulator
        }, {
            ranges: {},
            days: {},
            grouped: [],
        });

        return groupedObject.grouped;
    }
}
```

Which yields this:

```
[
   {
      "days":"Monday-Friday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "days":"Wednesday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"6:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "days":"Saturday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"4:00 PM"
   }
]
```

I'm really close but the problem is if a store has different hours in the middle of a range it doesn't break apart the days, ie Wednesday is open to 6 but every other weekday is open to 5. It would return M-F 9-5, and W 9-6. So in this scenario I would like this:

```
[
   {
      "days":"Monday-Tuesday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "days":"Wednesday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"6:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "days":"Thursday-Friday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"5:00 PM"
   },
   {
      "days":"Saturday",
      "open":"8:00 AM",
      "close":"4:00 PM"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look to open and close and add a new object. Otherwise change the days property.

```js
var data = [{ dayOfWeek: "Monday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "5:00 PM" }, { dayOfWeek: "Tuesday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "5:00 PM" }, { dayOfWeek: "Wednesday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "6:00 PM" }, { dayOfWeek: "Thursday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "5:00 PM" }, { dayOfWeek: "Friday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "5:00 PM" }, { dayOfWeek: "Saturday", open: "8:00 AM", close: "4:00 PM" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { dayOfWeek, open, close }) => {
        if (!r.length || r[r.length - 1].open !== open || r[r.length - 1].close !== close)
            r.push({ days: dayOfWeek, open, close });
        else
            r[r.length - 1].days = r[r.length - 1].days.split('-').slice(0, 1).concat(dayOfWeek).join('-');                
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The days are grouped wrong and the hours are also incorrect.